# Why would a log and linear model coefficients for the same dummy variable have different signs?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

Suppose you have data with the following variables:

- Years of education
- Wage rate
- Region of the country. (Northeast, South, Midwest, or West)

With the following R code:

```
manhattan <- lm(log(earnings) ~ region * education, data = CPSSW8)
brooklyn <- lm(earnings ~ region * education, data = CPSSW8)
stargazer(manhattan, brooklyn, type = "text", 
  column.labels = c("manhattan", "brooklyn"), table.layout = "ct")
```

\begin{array}{lllcc}
& \text{manhattan} & \text{brooklyn} & \text{(SE manhattan)} & \text{(SE brooklyn)} \\\hline
\text{regionMidwest} & -0.053& 0.148& (0.036)& (0.653)\\
\text{regionSouth}  &-0.151***&  -0.903& (0.033)& (0.595)\\
\text{regionWest}  &-0.052& 0.557& (0.034) &(0.618)\\
\text{education}  &0.092***& 1.794***& (0.002) &(0.033)\\
\text{regionMidwest:education}   &-0.001& -0.112**& (0.003)& (0.047)\\
\text{regionSouth:education}   &0.005** & -0.037& (0.002) &(0.043)\\
\text{regionWest:education}     & 0.001& -0.080*& (0.002) &(0.044)\\
\end{array}

Why is the coefficient South:education positive in manhattan and negative in brooklyn?

Comment: It is possible to have zero earnings in your data?

Answer (score 0):

I notice firstly you have log transformed the earnings in Manhatten but not in Brooklyn. While in univariate analysis, a negative coefficient for a natural scale outcome will usually produce a negative coefficient on the log scale, this is not always the case, and multiple adjustment may compound this issue.

For the sake of conversation, I will assume that the stratified analysis is done with a similar scale of the outcome variable, specifically the natural scale. I recommend you run your analyses with comparable scales if you aim to compare effects.

Region is a 4 level factor. A referent value, Northeast, for region is omitted from reported results. The intercept, which you have not reported here, gives the expected earnings for the northeast having 0 years of education. This is an extrapolated value. All other region effects report a mean difference in earnings having 0 years' education at the other regions. The effect of education is an expected difference in earnings for a year of education among people living in the northeast.

The south:education interaction is the difference in the average earnings difference for a years' education comparing the south to the northeast. If this value is negative, people in the south tend to earn less for their extra education than do people in the northeast. If it is positive, the earnings increase for a year of education is greater for those in the south than for those in the northeast.